# How to dynamically change a variable name or variable type on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I can't use eval() and window[], because they don't work for me for some reason.

Here I'm trying to make a method to make the creation of a new JButton to be easier and more space efficient since I will be making a LOT of the same buttons but with a slight difference. I just don't know how to change the Class (type) and class (variable name).

```
public void makeButton(JButton specificButton, JFrame frame, String text, int[] border) {
        specificButton = new JButton();
        specificButton.setText(text);
        frame.add(specificButton);
        specificButton.setBounds(border[0], border[1], border[2], border[3]);
        
        
        specificButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                myClass myclass = new myClass();// Example
                myclass...
            }
        });
    }
```

I found no other potential option.

Comment: it's possible I guess

Comment: But still what am I supposed to do here?

Comment: ok fixed the tag. Also by class i mean this 'Class class = new Class()' <--

Comment: `Class class = new Class();` does not work in Java since `class` is a keyword and cannot be used as variable name. `java.lang.Class` has only a private constructor, so `new Class()` does not work either. `Object object = new Object();` would work, but does nothing.

Comment: the 'Class' and 'class' are placeholders and are example words. I know that Class is a keyword. So now I changed it to myClass and myclass.

Comment: So are you saying that you want the action to create a different class for each button?

Comment: The `setBounds` indicates that you're using a `null` layout, which will lead you to nothing but more trouble in the future.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: Yes I want to use the parameters as everything needed for the button (since the only difference is creating an instance of the specific class and a method from that class) and because I've designed it in way to only instantiate and show the frame (in the class constructor) only when the button is pressed

Comment: soo can anyone help with a potential answer

Comment: _can anyone help with a potential answer_ most probably not before you describe your _real_ problem (instead of the problems you have with an assumed solution :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to pass the action as a `Runnable` to the method, something like:

```
public JButton makeButton(JFrame frame, String text, Runnable runnable) {

    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText(text);

    frame.add(button);

    button.addActionListener(event -> {
      frame.setVisible(false);

      runnable.run();
    });

    return button;
}
```

Which you would use like this:

```
JButton button1 = makeButton(frame, "button 1", () -> {
    // TODO action for button 1
 });

JButton button2 = makeButton(frame, "button 2", () -> {
   // TODO action for button 2
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But also, on the suggestion to transition to a non-null layout, should I apply it to all of my frame related classes or is it ok since they still work as well as before?

Comment: I am not an expert on Swing layouts, but my understanding is you should use layouts for everything and do not use setBounds at all.